# Value geting copied to pointer automatically in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I have a program here that is suppose to be the solution of [this](https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/635101/dashboard#s=p0) problem.

My code is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


 int compare(char *,char*[],int);

 int compare(char *s,char *tab[],int i)
{
  int j=0;
  for(;j<i;j++) {
    if(strcmp(s,tab[j])==0)
        return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

 int main(){

  int T=0,N=0,M=0,cas=0;
  char g_path[100]={0},*tab[10000]={0};

  int i=0;

  /*#ifndef judge
    freopen("input.txt","r",stdin);
    freopen("output.txt","w",stdout);
  #endif*/

  scanf("%d",&T);

  while(T--) {
    scanf("%d %d",&N,&M);
    int cnt=0;
    i=0;
    while(N--) {
        scanf("%s",g_path);
        char *s = strtok(g_path,"/");
        while(s!=NULL) {
            tab[i++]=s;
            s=strtok(NULL,"/");
        }
    }

    while(M--) {
        char m_path[100]={0};
        scanf("%s",m_path);
        char *s1 = strtok(m_path,"/");  //problem here
        while(s1!=NULL) {
            int k=compare(s1,tab,i);
            if(k==0){
                cnt++;
                tab[i++]=s1;
            }
            s1=strtok(NULL,"/");
        } 
    }
    printf("Case #%d: %d\n",(cas++)+1,cnt);
}
}
```

The problem is that suppose the input is :

```
1
0 2
/hhh/jjj/kk
/hhh/jjj/kl
```

the output is suppose to be 4. That is the number of directories that needs to be created is 4.

But the output i obtained is 3. While running debugger i found that the "kl" part in the 4th line is copied to the tab as its third element(tab[2]) and this happens as soon as it reads that line (as soon as `scanf("%s",m_path);` gets executed for the second time). Because of this the comparisons succeed at  that point which is not the desired output. I hope i'm clear about my question.

Comment: Why the output is supposed to be 4?

Comment: The output is supposed to be 4 because we need to create 4 directories: 1.hhh 2.jjj 3.kk and 4.kl. But the problem is that kl is getting copied to tab[2] automatically as soon as i enter the line `/hhh/jjj/kl`.

Comment: Oh OK and what does the magic numbers 0 and 0 2 mean?

Comment: its not 0 in the first line. My mistake. its 1 that shows the no. of test cases and then 0 shows no. of lines of directory path that already exists and 2 shows no. of lines of directory path that we need to create.

Comment: Do you know how pointers work? In particular, how pointer variables do not contain strings, only point to them?

Comment: Note that your algorithm won't work at all if the input is `"/hhh/jjj/kkk", "/hhh/kkk/jjj"`. Your algorithm is only looking for unique strings and it would find 3: `"hhh", "jjj", "kkk"`, but the answer is that 5 directories need to be created: `"/hhh", "/hhh/jjj", "/hhh/jjj/kkk",  "/hhh/kkk", "/hhh/kkk/jjj"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***VARIABLES INSIDE A LOOP GO OUT OF SCOPE afterwards!***

---

Here is the fixed code for the case you are mentioning (make sure you test for more cases and debug if needed):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


// UNNEEDED int compare(char *,char*[],int);

int
compare(char *s, char tab[10000][100], int i)
{
    int j = 0;
    for (; j < i; j++) {
    if (strcmp(s, tab[j]) == 0)
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int
main()
{
    int T = 0,
    N = 0,
    M = 0,
    cas = 0;
    char g_path[100] = { 0 }, tab[10000][100] = { {0} };

    int i = 0;
    scanf("%d", &T);

    while (T--) {
    scanf("%d %d", &N, &M);
    int cnt = 0;
    i = 0;
    while (N--) {
        scanf("%s", g_path);
        char *s = strtok(g_path, "/");
        while (s != NULL) {
            strcpy(tab[i++], s);
            s = strtok(NULL, "/");
        }
    }

    while (M--) {
        char m_path[100] = { 0 };;
        scanf("%s", m_path);
        char *s1 = strtok(m_path, "/"); // problem here
        while (s1 != NULL) {
            int k = compare(s1, tab, i);
            if (k == 0) {
                cnt++;
                strcpy(tab[i++], s1);
            }
            s1 = strtok(NULL, "/");
        }
    }
    printf("Case #%d: %d\n", (cas++) + 1, cnt);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
C02QT2UBFVH6-lm:~ gsamaras$ pico main.c
C02QT2UBFVH6-lm:~ gsamaras$ gcc -Wall main.c
C02QT2UBFVH6-lm:~ gsamaras$ ./a.out
1
0 2
/hhh/jjj/kk
/hhh/jjj/kl
Case #1: 4
```

---

So what has happened? You were using `tab`, which was an array of 10000 char pointers. You would assign the pointer to the start of `s1`.

However, `s1` would point to `m_path` which is nested variable, created inside the `while(M--)` loop. So when the loop starts, `m_path` gets created, when the loop terminates, `m_path` goes out of scope and thus gets destroyed.

So when you were going to check your second case, you would check `tab` which would now (because it was assigned `s1`, which was assigned to `m_path`) point to *invalid* data, i.e. data that have gone out scope, causing **UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR**.

However, in your case, you were (un)lucky to not get a *segmentation fault*, thus the program just checked garbage and thus could not provide the correct result.

---

How did i cure your problem?

One way to do it is: make `tab` a 2D array and **deep copy** the string that `s1` points to, to `tab[i]`, using [strcpy()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/) function of course.

Now, when `m_path` went out of scope, `tag` simply didn't care, because it had stored inside it the strings itselves, not pointers!

Comment: Well written answer!

Comment: This is a new knowledge. Many many Thanks. And very well explained (needs special mention).

Comment: @Midhun and roelofs thank you guys, made my day! Midhun, hadn't you asked a good question (thus my +1), I wouldn't be able to post such an answer! :)